# Adicionar item ao menu administrativo para salvar valor personalizado

Tags: wordpress

Estou tentando adicionar um anúncio no meio da postagem do WordPress.

```
<?php
    $paragraphAfter = 3; //display after the first paragraph
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
    $content = explode("</p>", $content);
    for ($i = 0; $i <count($content); $i++ ) {
    if ($i == $paragraphAfter) { ?>
    <div class="googlepublisherpluginad" style="text-align: center; width: 100%; height: auto; clear: none;">

    </div>
    <?php }
    echo $content[$i] . "</p>";
    } ?>
```

O código funciona. Mas tentei adicionar um item no menu do administrador... foi adicionado.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'addAdminMenu' );
function addAdminMenu(){
    add_menu_page('Add Adsense', 'Adsense', 'manage_options', 'adsense-page', 'admin_pg_function', '', 3);
}

function admin_pg_function(){
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options')){
        wp_die( __( 'Você não possui premissão duficiente para acessar esta página.' ) );
    }

    ?>
    <div style="width:100%;">
    <h1>Adicionar Adsense</h1>
    <textarea>Olá</textarea>

<?php }
```

Meu problema agora é salvar o que eu digitar naquela página, e como recuperá-lo e chamar na página `single.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível fazer isso com "força bruta" criando um formulário nessa página de opções e adicionando um `admin_init` que vai observar se esse formulário foi enviado e se estiver tudo seguro (`check_admin_referer`) e sanitizado (procedimento padrão para qualquer formulário) vai gravar isso na tabela de opções (`update_option`).

Mas o indicado é usar o [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) que se encarrega principalmente da segurança no processamento do formulário. O seguinte exemplo foi adicionado por mim ao [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages#Example_.232) e a única mudança que fiz aqui -além de traduzir os comentários- foi trocar o `add_options_page` do original (adiciona a página como sub-menu do Settings/Configurações) para `add_menu_page` (adiona a página como um menu principal).
<sub>Sugestão: usar `add_theme_page` para que seja um sub-menu do Appearance/Aparência.</sub>

A vantagem de adicionar como sub-menu é que esse é o tipo de página que visitamos muito pouco, acho que é uma poluição do menu principal adicionar items que são pouco usados.

O resultado é este:
[image: menu wordpress personalizado]

E para pegar essas opções no tema use:

```
$my_options = get_option( 'my_option_name' ); 
// mostra a variável, use $my_options['nome_da_opcao'] para pegar valores individuais
var_dump($my_options);
```

PLUGIN
<sub>se trocar de Theme quer que isto continue funcionando, então **não** colocamos dentro de `functions.php`</sub>

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Minhas Opções
 * Plugin URI: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/106105/201
 * Description: Adiciona menu/submenu com opções personalizadas
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: brasofilo
*/

class MySettingsPage
{
    /**
     * Guarda o valor das nossas opções
     */
    private $options;

    /**
     * Iniciar plugin
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_plugin_page' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Adicionar menu
     */
    public function add_plugin_page()
    {
        // This page will be under "Settings"
        add_menu_page(
            'Settings Admin', 
            'My Settings', 
            'manage_options', 
            'my-setting-admin', 
            array( $this, 'create_admin_page' )
        );
    }

    /**
     * HTML do menu
     */
    public function create_admin_page()
    {
        // Pega as opção armazenadas
        $this->options = get_option( 'my_option_name' );
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>My Settings</h2>           
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                // Imprime todos nossos settings
                settings_fields( 'my_option_group' );   
                do_settings_sections( 'my-setting-admin' );
                submit_button(); 
            ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Registrar e adicionar opções
     */
    public function page_init()
    {        
        register_setting(
            'my_option_group', // Option group
            'my_option_name', // Option name
            array( $this, 'sanitize' ) // Sanitize
        );

        add_settings_section(
            'setting_section_id', // ID
            'My Custom Settings', // Title
            array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), // Callback
            'my-setting-admin' // Page
        );  

        add_settings_field(
            'id_number', // ID
            'ID Number', // Title 
            array( $this, 'id_number_callback' ), // Callback
            'my-setting-admin', // Page
            'setting_section_id' // Section           
        );      

        add_settings_field(
            'title', 
            'Title', 
            array( $this, 'title_callback' ), 
            'my-setting-admin', 
            'setting_section_id'
        );      
    }

    /**
     * Sanitizar cada opção conforme necessário
     *
     * @param array $input Contém todas nossas opções como chaves da array (array keys)
     */
    public function sanitize( $input )
    {
        $new_input = array();
        if( isset( $input['id_number'] ) )
            $new_input['id_number'] = absint( $input['id_number'] );

        if( isset( $input['title'] ) )
            $new_input['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['title'] );

        return $new_input;
    }

    /** 
     * Imprimir o texto Section
     */
    public function print_section_info()
    {
        print 'Enter your settings below:';
    }

    /** 
     * Imprime a opção "id_number"
     */
    public function id_number_callback()
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="text" id="id_number" name="my_option_name[id_number]" value="%s" />',
            isset( $this->options['id_number'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['id_number']) : ''
        );
    }

    /** 
     * Imprime a opção "title"
     */
    public function title_callback()
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="text" id="title" name="my_option_name[title]" value="%s" />',
            isset( $this->options['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['title']) : ''
        );
    }
}

// Executar somente se estivermos na área administrativa (is_admin)
if( is_admin() )
    $my_settings_page = new MySettingsPage();
```